# Storing Customer Subscription ID issue

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am having an issue storing the stripe subscription ID on my database. As far as I know, I have done everything correct in correspondence to the stripe documentation, however I still cannot store the data. The data is registering as NULL. Can someone help shed some light on this for me? Please go easy on me, I just learned PHP 3 weeks ago and am relatively new to OOP in PHP.

Thanks!

Here is my stripe webhook once the customer subscription is created

```
  {
  "id": "evt_18tlxxHPUld5pqVxOX3YKx6g",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2016-06-15",
  "created": 1473892493,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "sub_9CAIqC9yUTkAPG",
      "object": "subscription",
      "application_fee_percent": null,
      "cancel_at_period_end": false,
      "canceled_at": null,
      "created": 1473892492,
      "current_period_end": 1474497292,
      "current_period_start": 1473892492,
      "customer": "cus_9CAI8co126bZId",
      "discount": null,
      "ended_at": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {},
      "plan": {
        "id": "product0",
        "object": "plan",
        "amount": 4700,
        "created": 1472151609,
        "currency": "usd",
        "interval": "month",
        "interval_count": 1,
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {
          "subscription": "product0"
        },
        "name": "Product0 Plan",
        "statement_descriptor": null,
        "trial_period_days": null
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "start": 1473892492,
      "status": "trialing",
      "tax_percent": null,
      "trial_end": 1474497292,
      "trial_start": 1473892492
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 2,
  "request": "req_9CAIgRMh75t4cd",
  "type": "customer.subscription.created"
}
```

And here is the corresponding case statement in my webhook.php file:

```
  case 'customer.subscription.created':
  //DEFINE EVENT OBJECT IN ACCORDANCE TO STRIPE WEBHOOK DOCUMENTATION
  $event_json = json_decode($input);
  $event = \Stripe\Event::retrieve($event_json->id);
  //END DEFINE EVENT OBJECT

  //ATTEMPTS TO RETRIEVE CUSTOMER INFORMATION FROM WEBHOOK.
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($event->data->object->customer);
  $plan = $event->data->object->plan->id;
  $subscription_id=$event->data->object->id;
    switch($plan)
    {
      case 'product0':
        //GET STRIPE CUSTOMER 
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($event->data->object->customer);
        //GET CUSTOMER EMAIL FROM STRIPE DATABASE
        $email = $customer->email;

        //UPDATE SQL TABLE WITH STRIPE SUBSCRIPTION ID 
        $sql    = "UPDATE users_stripe_infoProduct SET product0 = '$subscription_id' WHERE email = '$email' ";
        $query  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        //SEND EMAIL TO CUSTOMER IF QUERY WAS SUCCESSFUL
        if ($query)
        {
          $email = $customer->email;
          // Sending your customers the amount in pennies is weird, so convert to dollars
          $from    = "billing@anthonymoto.com";
          $to      = $email;
          $subject = "Subscription Created";
          $email_message = 'Hi,<br> We wanted to let you know what your subscription was successfully created!
                      <br><br>
                      If you have already verified your email address, can login and access your content by simply by clicking <a href ="www.anthonymoto.com/login.php">this link. </a>
                      <br><br>

                      <br>
                      Anthony Moto Support Team';
          $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
          $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
          $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
          mail($to,$subject,$email_message, $headers);
        }
      break;
```

Comment: Anthony, where is the $event object defined?  Is it before defining the lines that define $plan and $subscription_id?  I can see that $event is defined in the case statement, but not earlier.

Comment: HI Craig, The event object is actually defined before my switch-case, however I have moved it above the $customer variable for the community to see.

Comment: Hi Craig, I've edited my code to add more commenting so it is easier to follow.

Comment: ok - where are you defining $conn?

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump($event)?  is it returning the value that you're expecting?

Comment: Hi Craig, 
$conn is located in my dbconfig.php file. I can verify that the connection works because when the user signs up, their email address gets added to my SQL database.

Regarding your question on var_dump, I'm not sure how to implement a var_dump within a webhook. How would I view the var_dump live when the webhook is being sent? I have tried passing var_dump($event) to the email that is sent, however it does not show anything in the email.

Comment: Rather than var_dump, you could echo $event to a text file, e.g. put this line right after you define $event:  file_put_contents('event.txt', print_r($event, TRUE));  Then, execute your code and then view event.txt in an editor ( or just 'cat event.txt' from the command line).

Comment: Hi Craig, 
Thanks for the tip. The event.txt that I created actually is empty. Which means that the JSON isn't being sent. Now the problem is that I'm obviously receiving the webhook because I'm getting an email sent to myself (as programmed in the code), but the JSON body is empty.

Comment: Hi Craig, 
Thanks to your troubleshooting tips, I was able to figure out the issue. I defined $event =$event_json->id. This caused problems because I was pointing to an object that did not exist. thanks for all the help!

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Good luck!